# Discrete Event Simulation without global Queue?

Tags: functional-programming, simulation, reactive-programming, frp

I am thinking about modelling a material flow network. There are processes which operate at a certain speed, buffers which can overflow or underflow and connections between these.

I don't see any problems modelling this in a classic Discrete Event Simulation (DES) fashion using a global event queue. I tried modelling the system without a queue but failed in early stages. Still I do not understand the underlying reason why a queue is needed, at least not for events which originate "inside" the network.

The idea of a queue-less DES is to treat the whole network as a function which takes a stream of events from the outside world and returns a stream of state changes. Every node in the network should only be affected by nodes which are directly connected to it. I have set some hopes on Haskell's arrows and Functional Reactive Programming (FRP) in general, but I am still learning.

An event queue looks too "global" to me. If my network falls apart into two subnets with no connections between them and I only ask questions about the state changes of one subnet, the other subnet should not do any computations at all. I could use two event queues in that case. However, as soon as I connect the two subnets I would have to put all events into a single queue. I don't like the idea, that I need to know the topology of the network in order to set up my queue(s).

So

- is anybody aware of DES algorithms which do not need a global queue?
- is there a reason why this is difficult or even impossible?
- is FRP useful in the context of DES?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the first point, no I'm not aware of any *discrete-event simulation* (DES) algorithms that do not need a global event queue. It is possible to have a hierarchy of event queues, in which each event queue is represented in its parent event queue as an event (corresponding to the time of its next event). If a new event is added to an event queue such that it becomes the queue's next event, then the event queue needs to be rescheduled in its parent to preserve the order of event execution. However, you will ultimately still boil down to a single, global event queue that is the parent of all of the others in hierarchy, and which dispatches each event.

Alternatively, you could dispense with DES and perform something more akin to a *programmable logic controller* (PLC) which reevaluates the state of the entire network every small increment of time. However, typically, that would be a lot slower (it may not even run as fast as real-time), because most of the time it would have nothing to do. If you pick too big a time increment, the simulation may lose accuracy.

The simplest answer to the second point is that, ultimately, to the best of my knowledge, it is impossible to do without a global event queue. Each simulation event needs to execute at the correct time, and - since time cannot run backwards - the order in which events are dispatched matters. The current simulation time is defined by the time that the current event executes. If you have separate event queues, you also have separate clocks, which would make things very confusing, to say the least.

In your case, if your subnetworks are completely independent, you could simulate each subnetwork individually. However, if the state of one subnetwork affects the state of the total network, and the state of the total network affects the state of each subnetwork, then - since an event is influenced by the events that preceded it, can only influence the events that follow, but cannot influence what preceded it - you have to simulate the whole network with a global event queue.

If it's any consolation, a true DES simulation does not perform any processing in between events (other that determining what the next event is), so there should be no wasted processing in one subnetwork if all the action is taking place in another.

Finally, *functional reactive programming* (FRP) is *absolutely* useful in the context of a DES. Indeed, I now write of lot of my DES simulations in Scala using this approach.

I hope this helps!

**UPDATE**: Since writing the above, I've used *[Sodium](https://github.com/SodiumFRP/sodium)* (an excellent *FRP* library, which was referenced by the OP in the comments below), and can add some further explanation: *Sodium* provides a means for subscribing to events, and for performing actions when those events occur. However, here I'm using the term *event* in a general sense, such as a button being clicked by a user in a *GUI*, or a network package arriving, etc. In other words, the events are not necessarily *simulation* events.

You can still use *Sodium*—or any other *FRP* library—as part of a simulation, to subscribe to simulation events and perform actions when they occur; however, these tools typically have no built-in support for simulation, and so you must incorporate a simulation engine as the source of simulation events, in the same way that a *GUI* is incorporated as the source of user interaction events. It is within this engine that the global event queue must reside.

Incidentally, if you are trying to perform parallel or distributed simulation model execution, things get considerably more complicated. You have multiple event queues in these situations, but they must be synchronized (giving the appearance of a single queue). The two basic approaches are *conservative synchronization* and *optimistic synchronization*.

Comment: Encouraged by you, I looked at FRP a bit more and I could not see an event queue at all. Where do you see the queue in an FRP-style DES?

Comment: I'd be happy to answer that, but could you clarify what you mean by "see the queue"? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: In Sodium and Reactive Banana (Haskell) verything seems to orbit around Behaviors (aka Signals) and Events and ways to compose networks thereof. There was no explicit notion of a queue. When you do DES the FRP way, what role does a global event queue play there?

Comment: By the sound of it (I'm not familiar with Sodium, Reactive Banana or Haskell), it appears that the event queue is hidden behind Behaviors/Signals and Events.

Comment: (Whoops! Hit return a little early.) In other words, there is still a global event queue, which is used to schedule events and to dispatch them for execution, but you have no direct access to it. This is quite normal, since end-user simulation code should not be able to manipulate the event queue, aside from scheduling/descheduling events. When you specify a behavior to happen after a period of time, you are (under the hood) creating an event, adding that event to the event queue and specifying what happens (the actions) when the event is dispatched. Hope this helps.

Comment: When you do DES in Scala, do you still see the event queue or is it also hidden? Are you using Scala.React?

Comment: Mike, could you recommend a Scala library for DES? Something similar to SimPy for Python.

Comment: Tautvydas: I'm working on one of my own, but it's more of a personal project, right now, so I can't recommend it. There is a Scala simulation library called ScalaTion, which I have not used, and there are a number of Java-based simulation libraries, such as DESMO-J. How useful they are will depend upon your requirements...